# Jquery Selectbox get the value when selected and set to textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectbox

Hi I am new to javascript, html and jquery. I would really appreciate any help or suggestion thanks in advance. I am trying to get the value of my jquery select box and set the value to the textfield everytime they select something in the selectbox it will automatically change the value of text box. I am using the code below but I am just wonderingw what seems to be wrong in the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#loc').change(function(){
  var val = $('#loc').val();
  $("#com").val(val);
});

</script>              
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide your html code as well.

Comment: Include jquery , Write your code inside document.ready and if that is not a problem show html as well.

Comment: the script given looks just fine, perhaps relevant HTML will help us to help you better.

Answer (score -1):

You means the innerHTML of option not value?
Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#loc').change(function(){
  var val = $( "#loc option:selected" ).text();
  $("#com").val(val);
});

</script>              
</html>
```